# NoClassDefFoundError for zookeeper by replacing the log4j with relaod4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-zookeeper

Due to the recent exposure of log4j vulnerabilities our client has serious concerns about it. They asked us to remove or replace all the `log4j ver.1` with `ver.2` but unfortunately this is not possible for us to make such a big change.We did a workaround and replaced the `log4j ver.1` with `reload4j` and majority of components are working fine this with change.

Unfortunately we have some binaries in our product like `(elastic-search/logstash/zookeeper)` which are using either the older version of `log4j ver.2` **(log4j-core-2.11.x < 2.17.1)** or still using the `log4j ver.1` **(log4j-1.2.16)**.
For these we made the direct change in */lib/* directory and replaced the old jars with latests, this works fine for `elastic-search/logstash`. But when we did the same with `zookeeper` by replacing **log4j with reload4j** we're now facing the following exception when starting the component.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/jmx/HierarchyDynamicMBean
    at org.apache.zookeeper.jmx.ManagedUtil.registerLog4jMBeans(ManagedUtil.java:50)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:74)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:52)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.jmx.HierarchyDynamicMBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 mor
```

- zookeeper current version : 2.4.6
- latest stable release : 3.7.0

Latest stable release is still using **log4j-1.2.17**.

Can someone please guide the workaround. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Asked the same question to the owner of this library. [Here](https://github.com/qos-ch/reload4j/issues/44) is the further detail and answer of this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setting the system property zookeeper.jmx.log4j.disable=true will fix the issue. See also the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-docs/src/main/resources/markdown/zookeeperJMX.md#log4j-mbeans-deprecated).